# Why does the new Kafka Direct Stream in Spark Streaming take a set of topics?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

i.e. KafkaUtils.createDirectStream

Wouldn't you want a separate DStream for each topic? I ask because I currently have N topics and each holds different type of data (in this case Protobuf objects of different types). Obviously this is intentional otherwise each Kafka Direct DStream would take a single topic as a string. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The direct stream gives you access to each individual topicpartition.  So if you have a number of related topics, with similar but not quite identical processing requirements, you can easily handle them in a single stream.